# Passando dados de uma visão para outra

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tentando implementar a seguinte função, quando o usuário clicar no botão editar, ele enviaria para a página "criar" só que populada.
porém quando tento fazer isso, ele envia mas sem nada.

no meu xhtml está assim

```
<p:commandButton value="Deletar" icon="fa fa-fw fa-remove"
                type="submmit" action="#{proprietarioBean.editar(proprietario)}"
                update="form" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" >
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{proprietarioBean.proprietario}" value="#{proprietario}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

No método `editar` estou somente dando um `setProprietario` e um redirect.

```
public String editar(Proprietario proprietario) {
       setProprietario(proprietario);
       setTelefones(telefoneService.buscar(getProprietario()));
       return "inserirProprietario.xhtml";
}
```

Até a linha do `setProprietario` o objeto `proprietario` não é `null`, logo deveria aparecer do outro lado da tela.

Comment: Posta o código do método `editar`, por favor

Comment: Se o bean proprietarioBean não tiver um escopo maior que o ViewScoped esta abordagem não irá funcionar. Favor informar o escopo do propretarioBean

Comment: esta viewScoped, qual recomenda?

Comment: @IgorVenturelli ok

Comment: @Danilo recomendo que você mantenha o escopo ViewScoped porém altere a forma de passar objetos. Ao invés de passar o objeto todo. envie um identificador como parametro na URL, e depois na outra tela recupere do banco de dados o objeto a partir da referência. Contudo se você não quiser alterar a abordagem agora, apenas troque o escopo para SessionScoped e sua implementação deve funcionar ;)

Comment: @Bonifacio valeu pela resposta, vou fazer passando apenas o ID para recuperar o objeto do outro lado.